# Discretization based on linear constraints

Tags: classification, linear

I'm looking to explore some data with particular requirements and I came up with this technique. Since I'm not an specialist in machine learning, I would like to know if there is any technique which resembles this I describe.

(Boldness denotes vectors)

Data comes in the form of $k$ real vectors with p variables $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^p$.

For any set $L$ of linear *constraints* (rules of the form $\mathbf{a}_{l}\mathbf{x}\le \mathbf{b}_{l}$ or $\mathbf{a}_{l}\mathbf{x}= \mathbf{b}_{l}$, with $a_l,b_l \in \mathbb{R}^p$) we can express each point $\mathbf{x_k}$ in the data as a boolean vector $\mathbf{v_k}\in \lbrace{0,1}\rbrace^L$ where $$v_{kl}=1 \iff \mathbf{a}_{l}\mathbf{x_k}\le \mathbf{b}_{l}$$
$$v_{kl}=0 \iff \mathbf{a}_{l}\mathbf{x_k}> \mathbf{b}_{l} $$
or, if its an equality constraint, $$v_{kl}=1 \iff \mathbf{a}_{l}\mathbf{x_k}= \mathbf{b}_{l}$$
$$v_{kl}=0 \iff \mathbf{a}_{l}\mathbf{x_k}\ge \mathbf{b}_{l}+\epsilon \quad \text{and}\quad \mathbf{a}_{l}\mathbf{x_k}\le \mathbf{b}_{l}-\epsilon$$

There are some sets of constraints in which the data point / boolean vector association ($\mathbf{x_k}\rightarrow \mathbf{v_k}$) is *unique* in the sense that no two data points share a same boolean vector.

I'm interested in finding a minimal cardinality set of constraints satisfying this requirement. So the problem variables are both the amount, type and coefficients  of this constraints.

Do you know if this idea has an specific name ? Do you know any other ideas to which it would relate ? Does it sounds like a valid exploratory scheme or just non-sense ?

Comment: The b's are supposed to be scalar, right?. Otherwise it is not clear to me the motivation of your question. I would take a look at Geometrical and Statistical Properties of Systems of Linear Inequalities with Applications in Pattern Recognition by Thomas Cover, and his papers on nearest neighbours. All to be found at http://www-isl.stanford.edu/~cover/cover-papers.html.